# Equipment recommendation

Tags: support

Can I ask question with the tag 'equipment recommendation' that deals with a particular product of a particular company?Can I ask for reviews about a particular model of product?Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 8):

In general we try to avoid product reviews on the site. There are a few reasons...

1. There are already sites that are dedicated to the purpose of photography equipment review and so provide a great deal more information and comparison.
2. They can lead to flame wars on the site. More common when you're talking camera brands, but can happen for other things to.
3. Tend to be opinion oriented and somewhat open ended discussions. While getting facts into a review should be a goal, there are a lot of openings for opinion to form the basis of the response.

The best way to tackle trying to get some information about the product is to think of wording one or more questions that take away the opinion side of it. Avoiding questions like "I was thinking of buying X and was wondering what you thought of it?" and instead look for questions like "I understand X has a limitation in some feature and I would like to understand what the practical effect that would have on my photography would be?" Or something to that effect. :)